# How to add preview or select font dynamically in html for font size and font type in google app script html file

Tags: html, jquery, css, google-apps-script, fonts

I am newbie in front-end development. I want to create a font selector kind of form which will take input text, font type and font size from user and change the input text accordingly. This is to show user the preview of selected font. Below is something I tried,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Oswald|Anton|Kaushan+Script|Rochester|Sacramento');

.openSans {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
.oswald {font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;}
.anton {font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;}
.kaushanScript {font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;}
.rochester {font-family: 'Rochester', sans-serif;}
.sacramento {font-family: 'Sacramento', sans-serif;}

.uppercase-text {text-transform: uppercase;}
.lowercase-text {text-transform: lowercase;}
.capitalize-text {text-transform: capitalize;}


body {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
.wrapper {padding: 10px;}
.fontsSelectBox-button {margin-top: 10px; }
select {width: 200px;}
fieldset {
    border: 0;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

input {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.fontForm {
    max-width: 600px;
}

.checkbox-label {
    display: inline-block;
    
}
    
.grid {
  margin: -10px;
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: -0.286em;
  position: relative;   
}

.grid-cell {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: ;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  direction: ltr;
}

.size1of1 {
    width: 100%;
}

.size1of2 {
    width: 50%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 18px;
}
.image 
{ 
position: relative; /* To help the image + text element to get along with the rest of the page*/ 
width: auto; /* for IE 6 */ 
} 
h2 
{ 
position: absolute; /* To place the text on the image*/
top: 200px; /* The exact location of the text from the top of the image*/
left: 0; /* Other beautification stuff */
width: 100%; 
}
/* Coloring time */
h2 span /* decorating the text within the span tag */
{ 
color:; 
font: ; 
letter-spacing: -1px; 
padding: 10px; 
}
h2 span.spacer { padding:0 5px; } /* to pad the background color of text to make it look more elegant */

 
</style>
<base target="_top">

    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      
          
    function myfunction(){
    (function($){
    var fontTxtField = $("#fontTxtField");
    var fontsSelectBox = $("#fontsSelectBox");

    $(fontsSelectBox).selectmenu({
        change : function(event, data) {
            fontTxtField.removeClass("openSans").removeClass("oswald")
            .removeClass("anton").removeClass("kaushanScript")
            .removeClass("rochester").removeClass("sacramento")
            .addClass(data.item.value);
            console.log(data)
        },
        icons: { button: "ui-icon-circle-triangle-s" }
    });
  
  var fontStyle;
    if (document.getElementById("uppercase").checked){
     fontStyle = document.getElementById("uppercase").value;
    }else if(document.getElementById("lowercase").checked){
    fontStyle = document.getElementById("lowercase").value;
    }else if(document.getElementById("capitalize").checked){
    fontStyle = document.getElementById("capitalize").value;
    }else{
    fontStyle = document.getElementById("normal").value;
    }
    $(fontStyle).change(function () {
        var value = this.value;
        switch(value) {
            case "uppercase":
                fontTxtField.addClass("uppercase-text").removeClass("lowercase-text").removeClass("capitalize-text");
            break;
            case "lowercase":
                fontTxtField.addClass("lowercase-text").removeClass("uppercase-text").removeClass("capitalize-text");
            break;
            case "capitalize":
                fontTxtField.addClass("capitalize-text").removeClass("uppercase-text").removeClass("lowercase-text");
            break;          
            case "normal":
            default:
                fontTxtField.removeClass("uppercase-text").removeClass("lowercase-text").removeClass("capitalize-text");;
            break;
        };
    });
   var inputFont = fontTxtField[0]['value']
   var si = fontsSelectBox[0]['options']['selectedIndex']
   var selectedFont = fontsSelectBox[0]['options'][si]['text']
})(jQuery);
}
    </script>
        <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link href="style.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">    
        <h1>Font Selector</h1>
        <fieldset class="fontForm grid">
    <div class="grid-cell">
            <div class="grid-cell size1of2">
    <div class="grid-cell size1of2">
                <label for="fontsSelectBox">Choose Font</label>
                <select id="fontsSelectBox" name="fontsSelectBox">
                <option value="openSans">Open Sans</option>
                <option value="oswald">Oswald</option>
                <option value="anton">Anton</option>
                <option value="kaushanScript">Kaushan Script</option>
                <option value="rochester">Rochester</option>
                <option value="sacramento">Sacramento</option>  
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid-cell size1of1">
                <label for="uppercase" class="checkbox-label"><input type="radio" name="fontStyle" value="uppercase" id="uppercase"> Uppercase</label>
                <label for="lowercase" class="checkbox-label"><input type="radio" name="fontStyle" value="lowercase" id="lowercase"> Lowercase</label>
                <label for="capitalize" class="checkbox-label"><input type="radio" name="fontStyle" value="capitalize" id="capitalize"> Capitalize</label>
                <label for="normal" class="checkbox-label"><input type="radio" name="fontStyle" value="normal" id="normal" checked> Normal</label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image"> <!-- the image container -->
    <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/776cbf_6940447e8d13424b9957749730292300~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_404,h_750,al_c,q_90,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/776cbf_6940447e8d13424b9957749730292300~mv2.webp" alt="" /> <!-- the image -->
    <h2>
    <span><div class="grid-cell image">
            <input type="text" name="fontTxtField" id="fontTxtField" placeholder="Your text here"/><span class='spacer'></span>
    </h2> 
      <div class="center">
      <p><button onclick="myfunction()">Submit</button></p>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>          
</body>
</html>
```

In above code I am able to change font type after Submit button which is I don't want and not able to change the font size or type (uppercase, lowercase..). Where I am doing wrong or what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the font and type are changing only when the form is submitted, and you want them to update when the selected option changes. If that's the case, you could use a [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) instead.

For example, in `select`, use:

```
<select id="fontsSelectBox" name="fontsSelectBox" onchange="myfunction()">
```

For `radio` inputs, you'll have to add the `onchange` event to each single input, so you might better use event listeners instead:

```
var rad = document.getElementsByName("fontStyle");
for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].addEventListener('change', myfunction);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use elementSef.style.fontSize to change the font size using js or jquery.

Comment: I actually don't want to change size. I just want to change whether it is capital or small and onward. You can check it in picture attached.